# Why does the Squoosh CLI rotate vertical pictures?

Tags: webp

I used the Squoosh CLI in order to compress my several pictures from JPEG to WebP.
However, some of the vertical pictures are somehow automatically rotated and become horizontal without my intent.
Some of the horizontal pictures are not rotated.
This happens only in using Squoosh CLI, no problem in using Desktop application and Online website.
In order to compress several pictures, Squoosh CLI is necessary, so what should I do for no rotation with Squoosh CLI?

Comment: Hi, please add in the code of your attempt, so we can comment on it

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Here is the code:
 
squoosh-cli 001.jpg --webp

Comment: I don't use or know `squoosh` but I guess it may be related to **EXIF** *"Auto-orient"*. Try looking at an image that rotates unexpectedly using `exiftool` or **ImageMagick** `identify -verbose UNHAPPY.JPG` to see if there are tags called *"orientation"*. You can/could strip them before conversion with either tool if they are the cuplrits.

Comment: I used `cwebp -preset photo -metadata all -mt` and some vertical photos got rotated automatically, and I suspect this is used in the backend by `squoosh`.

Interestingly it only happened w/ photos sent to me by an iphone user, my OnePlus phone's pictures have always retained their orientation